# SQL Server - IsDate function returning unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do something like this

```
when ISDATE(u.NewValue)=1 then CONVERT(varchar,cast(u.NewValue as date),23)
```

But sql server returns 1 for `2406` also as it is a date, so this

```
select ISDATE('2406')
```

returns 1.

Which is not the case.
And because of this I get the output like this `2406-01-01` which is wrong.

What should be the way to check if the value is actaully a date, when my data will be a date it will come in this format `2019-05-28 07:59:04.450`, so I want to capture only this type of data as date.

Can anyone suggest me the approach for this

Comment: if the data provided by the source is supposed to be a DATE but isn't then the problem is there

Comment: Scroll down and read the paragraph titled 'Remarks' in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: (1) why is `NewValue` not a date in the first place? If you use the right data type, junk like `2046` won't get in there. (2) [don't use varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) (3) think about `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CAST` (4) you can find bad data using `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, u.NewValue) IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `like`:

```
select (case when col like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
             then convert(datetime, col)
        end)
```

Depending on what your column looks like, you can relax the formatting requrements:

```
select (case when col like '%-%-% %:%:%.%'
             then try_convert(datetime, col)
        end)
```

I am surprised that SQL Server converts this to a date just using the year:

```
try_convert(date, '2019', 121)
```

The format can be incomplete.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@value)=1 AND @value between '1900' and '2036' THEN CONVERT(varchar(max),cast(@value as date),23) END` is more readable than all thos `[0-9]` ;)

Comment: Strangely when I do this `select case when '2019-05-23 16:51:31.000' like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
then 1 else 0 end` it works while this doesn't work `select StartDate from dbo.BatteryClass where 
cast(StartDate as varchar(500)) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: And the start date I copied from the table value only so it is the same value that is stored in the column

Comment: @Luuk - But then `1901` will be converted to date which is not a date but an integer

Comment: @PawanNogariya . . . Your result is not strange.  There is no guarantee that the `where` is executed before the `select`.  Only the `case` expression guarantees the order of evaluation.

Comment: @PawanNogariya , why is the year 1901 (or 2406) not a date? 1901 is 118 years ago, and 2406 is taking 387 years. How do you define a date ?

Comment: @Luuk - Because my requirement is to check if the string is of date format only, `1901` alone is not a date for my requirement but an integer. `1901-01-01` is a date for me

Comment: Then you could check the length of the input (also)   `when ISDATE(u.NewValue)=1 then CONVERT(varchar,cast(u.NewValue as date),23) AND len(u.NewValue)>4`  or, maybe you should check for a length of 10. (it's your data...)